# HBase to Delta Tables

Tags: azure, hadoop, hbase, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We are in the process of migrating a Hadoop Workload to Azure Databricks. In the existing Hadoop ecosystem, we have some HBase tables which contains some data(not big). Since, Azure Databricks does not support Hbase, we were planning if we can replace the HBase tables with Delta tables.
Is this technically feasible, if yes, is there any challenges or issues we might face during the migration or in the target system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes to the access patterns. HBase is OLTP system where you usually operate on individual records (read/insert/update/delete) and expect subsecond (or millisecond) response time.  Delta Lake, on other side is OLAP system designed for efficient processing of many records together, but it *could be* slower when you read individual records, and especially when you update or delete them.

If your application needs subseconds queries, especially with updates, then it make sense to setup a test to check if Delta Lake is the right choice for that - you may need to look onto Databricks SQL that is doing a lot of optimizations for fast data access.

If it won't fulfill your requirements, then you may look onto other products in Azure ecosystem, like, Azure Redis or Azure CosmosDB that are designed for OLTP-style data processing.

Comment: that's a fantastic way to explain. Really appreciate your answer. So, in this system the HBase is mostly used for read and not much insert/update/delete. That too on not a big dataset.
We cannot use Azure CosmosDB for the cost. So, we're planning to use and Azure SQL. Will that be good canidate

Comment: You can try Databricks SQL first, it may fit your requirements, especially if requests happen only at specific time of the day, etc. Otherwise, Azure SQL or Azure PostgreSQL could be a choice